# How to avoid duplication in my document writer?

Tags: c#, xml

I have these two methods which are generating two different xml files whose header section is same and detail section varies. The root node is different for both xml files. Here I have two methods written, one for each. I want to optimize the code by avoiding the duplication of code in these two methods. Can you please guide me achieve this?

```
private string GenerateType1XML(TypeHeader header, List<TypeDetail> TypeDetailList)
{

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder))
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement(xmlElementConfig.CreateType1RootNode);
            WriteTypeHeader(writer, header);
            foreach (TypeDetail typ in TypeDetailList)
            {
                WriteType1Detail(writer, typ);
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();

}

private string GenerateType2XML(TypeHeader header, List<TypeDetail> TypeDetailList)
{

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder))
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement(xmlElementConfig.CreateType2RootNode);
            WriteTypeHeader(writer, header);
            foreach (TypeDetail typ in TypeDetailList)
            {
                WriteType2Detail(writer, typ);
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a generic XML generator that receive an Action to execute your function. Something like

```
private string GenerateTypeXML(TypeHeader header, List<TypeDetail> TypeDetailList, string xmlRootNode Action<XmlWriter, TypeDetail> func)
{

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder))
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement(xmlRootNode);
            WriteTypeHeader(writer, header);
            foreach (TypeDetail typ in TypeDetailList)
            {
                func(writer, typ);
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();

}
```

and use it like that

```
private string GenerateType1XML(TypeHeader header, List<TypeDetail> TypeDetailList)
{
    return GenerateTypeXML(header, TypeDetailList, xmlElementConfig.CreateType1RootNode,  WriteType1Detail);
}

private string GenerateType2XML(TypeHeader header, List<TypeDetail> TypeDetailList)
{
    return GenerateTypeXML(header, TypeDetailList, xmlElementConfig.CreateType2RootNode, WriteType2Detail);
}
```

You might have to cast your "WriteType1Detail" to Action if it doesn't compile, I don't have visual studio right now

Comment: Nice! Delegates FTW! You're missing a `string` parameter for `xmlElementConfig.CreateType1RootNode` has to be `xmlElementConfig.CreateType2RootNode` for type-2.

Comment: Oops, fixed! :)

Comment: Both the solution are good and works very well, i went with secod approch of using Action since it recudes number of line of code and uses the Action feature provided. Thanks a lot for both of you guys. Bruno and Mats.

Answer (score 5):

You need to look at what's common to both methods:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder))
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement(/* different in the two methods */);
        WriteTypeHeader(writer, header);
        foreach (TypeDetail typ in TypeDetailList)
        {
            /* different in the two methods */
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

Looks like you could have a base class with a `GenerateXml` method calling into *abstract* members that derived types (`Type1XmlGenerator`, `Type2XmlGenerator`... whatever `Type1` and `Type2` means) can `override`:

```
public abstract class XmlGenerator
{
    protected abstract void WriteDetails(XmlWriter writer, TypeDetail type);
    protected abstract string XmlRootNode { get; }

    public string GenerateXml(TypeHeader header, IEnumerable<TypeDetail> details)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(builder))
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement(XmlRootNode);
                WriteTypeHeader(writer, header);
                foreach (TypeDetail detail in details)
                {
                    WriteDetails(writer, detail);
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have a `class Type1XmlGenerator : XmlGenerator` that will `override` the `WriteDetails` method with what you currently have in `WriteType1Detail`, and the `XmlRootNode` property getter implementation will return `xmlElementConfig.CreateType1RootNode`.

---

Now, writing/generating XML is a solved problem, doing that with a `StringBuilder` is error-prone. You should really look into what LINQ-to-XML (`System.Xml.Linq`) has in store for you.